# Accessing css property from scriptlet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, scriptlet

css

```
.myStyle {
height: 10px;
background-image: url(../myImage.png);
}
```

jsp

```
<img class=myStyle src=<% imageurl != null ? imageurl: (bacground-image property from my css)%> >
```

Is there any way to achieve this?
I don't want to hardcode the default url in my code, to allow change of default image by just changing the css property.

Comment: Can you explain why you do not use a property file instead?

Comment: I want to have a single point of change, rest of the styling properties including images can be updated by just updating the css.. this is just a peculiar case i have.

Comment: That is what property files are for in jsp. Here you will need JavaScript unless you want to read the actual CSS file in the jsp. http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-resourcebundle-properties-file-jsp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is a property file - for example like this http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-resourcebundle-properties-file-jsp/

```
# image default
myimage.default=../myImage.png
```

and

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
<%
ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("commonVariable");
/// commonVariable.properties file will be in WEB-INF/classess  folder

String defaultImage=resource.getString("myimage.default");
.
.
.
if (imageurl==null) imageurl=defaultImage;

%>

<img class="myStyle" src="<%= imageurl  %>" />
```

---

Alternative if you must

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2104580/295783

```
function setImageFromBG(img) {
  var style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
  img.src = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);
}

<img class="myStyle" src="<%= imageurl %>" onerror="setImageFromBG(this)" />
```

May loop if the bgimage code fails to give a good image too