# retrieve the size of a background image set to "cover"

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, cover, background-size

Good day all.
I have a div, with a background image with its size set to `cover`.

how do I get the background size with javascript, or jquery?

I mean, the background will fill the div with one of its dimensions, width or height, I would like to understand which are the width and height of the full (Computed)  image, not only the visible part.

```
<style>
body {width:100%; height:100%}
#fullCoverBg {background-image:url("ani_bg.jpg"); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:right;}  

@media all and (max-width : 1000px) {
/* small screens */
aside {height:30%; width:100%;}
#fullCoverBg {height:70%; width:100%;}
}

@media all and (min-width : 1001px) {
/* big screens */
aside {height:100%; width:30%;float:left;}
#fullCoverBg {height:100%;width:70%;float:left;}
}  
</style>    

<body>
<aside>this div stay on head on small devices, and go on the left side on big screens </aside>
<div id="fullCoverBg"></div>
</body>
```

let's say we resize the wwindow, we will see the background cover the entire div, and of course some parts will be not visible, becouse "cover" fill up the div in its width OR height... for each resize, which are the dimension of the full image (visible and invisible parts) ?

Comment: is the div and the image the same size.ie. did you set the image size to fit the div? if possible, please post html and css code of the image..

Comment: no, the image is set as background and its size is set to cover, so for different viewports, the image will have different sizes, different visible parts...

Comment: ok, i think i got you, thanks, let me see what i can do..when you set a background image in a div of 500px by 500px, won't the background-image show only 500px by 500px? the background image size will equal the div size..

Comment: again, i ask, post html and css code because i am not entirely understanding your question

Comment: I'm half way to a solution. Just a little while more and I'll have a complete one.

Comment: Alright, I've edited my answer to reflect the new solution.

Comment: There was some missing logic that I just added in. Grab the new code from my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're gonna want to preload the image.

```
var background = new Image();
background.src = "your-image.jpg";

var bgHeight = background.height;
var bgWidth = background.width;
```

Alright, here's the real answer. It took some thinking, and some borrowing of code from this answer: [How can I determine the background image URL of a div via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104149/how-can-i-determine-the-background-image-url-of-a-div-via-javascript)

But, I finally got it. I see you wanted a jQuery answer, but I work only in Native, JS, so sorry about the disconnect.

**EDIT: I found some missing logic, so I threw it in. Now it should be good to go, hopefully.**

http://jsfiddle.net/TLQrL/2/ - New link reflecting new logic

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var style = div.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(div, false);
var bg = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);

var background = new Image();
background.src = bg;

background.onload = function() {
    if (background.width > background.height) {
        var ratio = background.height / background.width;
        if (div.offsetWidth > div.offsetHeight) {
            var bgW = div.offsetWidth;
            var bgH = Math.round(div.offsetWidth * ratio);
            if (bgH < div.offsetHeight) {
                bgH = div.offsetHeight;
                bgW = Math.round(bgH / ratio);
            }
        } else {
            var bgW = Math.round(div.offsetHeight / ratio);
            var bgH = div.offsetHeight;
        }
    } else {
        var ratio = background.width / background.height;
        if (div.offsetHeight > div.offsetWidth) {
            var bgH = div.offsetHeight;
            var bgW = Math.round(div.offsetHeight * ratio);
            if (bgW > div.offsetWidth) {
                bgW = div.offsetWidth;
                bgH = Math.round(bgW / ratio);
            }
        } else {
            var bgW = Math.round(div.offsetWidth / ratio);
            var bgH = div.offsetWidth;
        }
    }
    console.log(bgW + ", " + bgH);
}
```

Comment: mh... I will get the "original" value of the image, I need the "computed" one

Comment: I will try to jsfiddle something... No promises though.

Comment: seams legit, I'll try it before accepting :) thanks!

Comment: Yeah, something is off, but I am fixing it now to add some logic that I missed. Give me a few more minutes.

Comment: Currently not working. Seems to return the width of the browser window.

Comment: @TCB13 is your image the size of your browser window? lol; The jsfiddle broke, so I'll have to try and test this out locally later

Comment: @ndugger no it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
fetch('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js').then(response => response.text()).then(text => eval(text)).then(() => {
    
    // i just fetch jquery to get it to work on code snippet
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var bg = new Image();
        bg.src = $('#myDiv').css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
        var ratio = Math.max($('#myDiv').width() / bg.width, $('#myDiv').height() / bg.height);
        var bgW = Math.round(ratio * bg.width);
        var bgH = Math.round(ratio * bg.height);
        console.log(bgW + ',' + bgH);
    });

})
```

```css
#myDiv {
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url('https://secure.static.tumblr.com/ebf8f98b59be30d14a267901c55c628a/woxut3t/YqAom1fhk/tumblr_static_843lnidcun0g0ks4co84gkg4c.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Outputs `NaN,NaN` on Safari 10.1 and Chrome 57.0.2987.133 both on macOS. Didn't test in any other browser.