# Getting error thrown in function with if + && condition

Tags: javascript

This is the function:

```
 window.addEventListener("load", function() {
     var firstGal = document.querySelector(".containsNext");

     var nextB = document.querySelector(".nondynamic");

     var displayed = document.getElementsByClassName('images')[0];

     nextB.addEventListener('click', function() {
         if (firstGal.style.opacity == 0 && displayed.style.backgroundImage ==  "url(http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/03/07/article-2575552-1C1A7B9400000578- 567_964x673.jpg)") {
             firstGal.style.transform = "rotateY(360deg)";
             firstGal.style.opacity = 1;
             firstGal.style.height = "200px";
             firstGal.style.width = "500px";
             firstGal.style.perspective = "400px";
             forwardSpain();
             } 
             else {
                   firstGal.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
                   firstGal.style.opacity = 0;
                   firstGal.style.perspective = "400px";
                   forwardSpain();
                  }

          });
 });
```

What I want is to test if the opacity of firstGal is 0 and if the background of the div ".images"(var = displayed/ this is dynamically created) has a specific backgroundImage Css value. Then run the code.
The code runs fine without the condition after "&&", but i cannot find the issue.

When the Spain button is clicked, the .images div gets a background image set, from an array. I want to check the backgroundImage style on it after the spain button is clicked. The dev tools/console return this:

Background-image: url(http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/03/07/article-2575552-1C1A7B9400000578-567_964x673.jpg);

Now my error could be how I assigned the variable, maybe querySelector would be better to find the element, there is only on .images class.
And I am not sure where to put the "" after the backgroundImage == . I have tried "url(" + 'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/03/07/article-2575552-1C1A7B9400000578-567_964x673.jpg' + ")") as well, but i just get the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
pen.js:149 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Looks like var displayed is undefined.

Link to full code, it is bit long, sorry for that, but it's just the above function which doesnt work. Line 65.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gPggLB?editors=001

Comment: check to see what the console is saying or step through it. My guess is that the condition `displayed.style.backgroundImage` doesn't have the value you are expecting.

Comment: @mwilson
the console gives me the value i have posted above for background-image.
I am not sure should I try displayed[0].style.etcetc.
I suspect the error is after the == operator, i.E. , how I am testing for the value.
console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
pen.js:149 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, I thought I had that in the original post, sorry

Comment: So, either `firstGal` or `displayed` is not what you expect it to be.  You will have to use a `console.log()` or debugger to see which is wrong and then figure out why.

Comment: If you're getting `Cannot read property 'style' of undfined` it's probably because `displayed` is null or doesn't have a style property. I'd check that variable to make sure it contains what you want.

Comment: @jfriend00
I am absolutely sure the firstGal works, if i comment out the condition after the &&, the function is invoked.
Now, the console says that the background property of displayed is url(etc), but I have to mention, the whole "displayed" element is created dynamically, I am not sure if this matters, but i know you can'y just add eventListeners to dynamically created elements. Maybe it has something to do with that.
What is your guys opinion how exactly the part after style.backgroundImage == should look?

Comment: @mwilson
yes, as mentioned int he previous comment, maybe because the element does not exist before all the scopes are parsed. It only comes to existence and gets css values after a click on the nation button. I will try to create another div, non dynamic, just css/html and see if that will work.

Comment: I have further tried this:
 var displayed = document.getElementsByClassName('images')[0],
style = displayed.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(displayed, false),
bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1)

Console says current style is undefined.

Comment: Kind of resolved this, but not to full happyness...
This is more complicated than it first seems, evident from this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104149/how-can-i-determine-the-background-image-url-of-a-div-via-javascript
I have to store the value in a variable and put that into the conditional statement, then it work, all else does not work.
There is an indirect problem with that, i will need to write many extra functions for what i want to achieve with this.