# How to get all image urls from a web page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

There are couple of ways to load image src urls using javascript, like using `document.images` or by selecting all `img` tags and get srcs.

However I can't figure out a way to image urls used within css.

For example, if the webpage has following css code, it loads `bg.png`, but I can't get that url using methods I mentioned above.

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url('bg.png');
}
```

Anyone has an idea how to get all these urls used within css?

Comment: `document.styleSheets` search the rules in each sheet?

Comment: Use `getComputedStyle`. Will it help you? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104149/how-can-i-determine-the-background-image-url-of-a-div-via-javascript

Comment: @evolutionxbox is it possible to access every individual stylesheet rules?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I think it would take forever to iterate through all the dom elements and each styles...

Comment: Do you need to only get the urls within CSS rules that have been applied to at least one element,  or to also get  urls from rules that have not been applied to any element?

Comment: @traktor either would be fine I think

Comment: I am wondering if it's possible with pure javascript privilege or by using some more power like chrome extension api or service worker

Comment: @emil, but you can iterate over all the elements using the `forEach()` method or the `for` loop + the method to which I gave you the link.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov yes that's possible, but it would be very slow

Comment: one other idea - the Resource Timing API collects data on outbound requests. Perhaps depending on your application you could use that to parse outbound image requests? that will catch everything mind, not just bg images but inline ones as well. https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/an-introduction-to-the-resource-timing-api/

Comment: @Squiggs. resource timing API is the perfect solution! Very performant as well as showing all the resource urls and initiators. Please write an answer so that I can accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Resource Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API) collects data on outbound requests, should leave capacity to collect images in both CSS and inline styles performantly.

Haven't tested this, but something akin to this should help you get started:

```
if ( !('performance' in window) ||
                 !('getEntriesByType' in window.performance) ||
                 !(window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource') instanceof Array)
                 ) {
                      alert('unsupported');
         } else {
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
               var resources = window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource');
               for(var index in resources) {

                  for(var properties in resources[index]) {
                      console.log(properties);
                      console.log(resources[index][properties]);
                  }
                
               }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

1. Loop all stylesheet rules
2. grab the document element from the stylesheet
3. find the background Image

```js
var sSheetList = document.styleSheets;
    for (var sSheet = 0; sSheet < sSheetList.length; sSheet++)
    {
        var ruleList = document.styleSheets[sSheet].cssRules;
        for (var rule = 0; rule < ruleList.length; rule ++)
        {
           if (rule.style.cssText.match(/background/)) {
           var selectorText = ruleList[rule].selectorText );
           var img = document.getElementsByClassName(selectorText);
           var style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false);
           if( style.backgroundImage ) {
               var bg = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
 //add to array here or whatever.
           }
           }
          
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Squiggs. I think you can't get rules if stylesheets is external though.